# Zabbix eth0 incoming traffic, triggering false alarms?

Tags: monitoring, ethernet, zabbix

I'm a bit confused right now, I just got this false alarm

[image]

I had an item set up to monitor incoming and outgoing traffic on my servers and despite it working as intended for A WHOLE MONTH, suddenly I get a peak, smaller than several others, that triggers an alert, here's the graph highlighting what triggered the alert (18 Sept, at 9am)

[image]

When this alert was triggered, my trigger function was set up as

```
{Basic Monitoring:net.if.in[eth0,bytes].avg(60)}>20M
```

So I increased the values to:

```
{Basic Monitoring:net.if.in[eth0,bytes].avg(120)}>25M
```

However, I'm a bit worried this might happen again, meaning I did not understand or setup the item/trigger wrong.

Here are both my item, and function used for this alert

[image]

[image]

Why or how did this happen?

Answer (score 2):

Your item gets data every 5 seconds (which is very frequent by the way, consider using a longer interval), your trigger used to check the average value over 60 seconds.
Without evaluating every single data value, I'd guess that previous peaks were shorter and the alerting one just happened to be there for a bit longer - to push the average for 60 seconds over the threshold.

A similar reason could be missing the values a few times. For example, getting only one value in 60 seconds over the threshold would immediately take the average up as well.